# Web page opened by Selenium has broken encoding

Tags: java, selenium, encoding

Hi I play with Java Selenium tests. I have some java tests and local web page which works well if I open it in browser. But if the page is opened by Selenium the encoding is broken. Can somebody tell me why? Html has charset=utf8 in the head. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: include your code... does the font look different than when you launch manually?

Comment: How do you conclude _encoding is broken_?

Comment: I see question marks in there. It is the sing of broken encoding isnt it?

Comment: I have it. The page is generated by PHP and the emails have been created from names by strtolower(). As I rewrite it to mb_strtolower it is ok. Its not my code...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was not related with the mistake in the code.